# How to "change the size" of an array [Pointers being used]

Tags: c++

So I have to implement a stack using an array built in a class, and if the "stack" ever fills up, I am supposed to increase the size of the array which I attempted, and failed. So I am just curious as to what I need to change in order to make this work.

```
class AbstractStack
{
private:
    Type elements; // elements in the array  
    Type max; 
    Type *s;
public:
    AbstractStack(Type num) { //CONSTRUCTOR
        elements= -1; 
        this->max = num; 
        s = new Type[max];
}

/* bunch of code that does not apply to this issue 


*/
void push ( Type e ) {             
   if (elements + 1 == max) { 
        cout << "Stack at max size, WIll increase size of array and add item" << endl; 
        Type *temp = new Type[max + (max/2)];
        for (int i = 0; i < elements+1; i++) { 
            temp[i] = s[i]; 
        }
        s = temp; 
        delete temp;
        elements++;
        s[elements] ;
        return; 
   }
   else { 
        elements++;
        s[elements] = e; 
   } 
}
```

When I take the size of this new s, I get the correct size of 1 larger than before because this function is only called when trying to add 1 element to the full stack, but when I attempt to use the top function, it just gives me 0 then I get like 50 lines of error codes starting in:

```
 *** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (top): 0x0000000000c53cf0 ***
  ======= Backtrace: =========
 /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7c619)[0x7fa34a270619]
 ./a.out[0x400c38]
 ./a.out[0x400b48]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fa34a215c05]
 ./a.out[0x400979]
```

Comment: You copy the pointer from ```temp``` to ```s```. You should swap those two.

Comment: I don't think you need `return` where it is, and you probably need to delete `s` instead of `temp`, then assign `temp` to `s`.

Comment: Type elements? Type max? If your Type is string, what's a max string?

Comment: You should consider upvoting and/or accepting answers you find useful here.

Answer (score 2):

```
Type elements; // elements in the array  
Type max;
```

These are both just `int`s, or `unsigned`s, or `size_t`s, or whatever you prefer for counting. They have nothing to do with `Type` whatsoever.

```
void push ( Type e ) {             
   if (elements + 1 == max) { 
        cout << "Stack at max size, WIll increase size of array and add item" << endl; 
        Type *temp = new Type[max + (max/2)];
```

After this you should increase `max` to `max*3/2`.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < elements+1; i++) {
```

Loop condition should be `i < elements`. You are using element zero, and `element[elements]` does not exist yet.

```
            temp[i] = s[i]; 
        }
        s = temp; 
        delete temp;
```

Last two lines should be `delete[] s` followed by `s = temp`.

```
        elements++;
        s[elements] ;
```

Last two lines should be `s[elements++] = e`;

```
        return;
```

`return` is redundant here.

```
   }
   else { 
        elements++;
        s[elements] = e;
```

Again, the last two lines should be `s[elements++] = e`;

```
   } 
}
```

Corrected and simplified version:

```
int elements;
int max;

// ...
void push ( Type e ) {
    if (elements + 1 == max) { 
        cout << "Stack at max size, WIll increase size of array and add item" << endl; 
        max += max/2;
        Type *temp = new Type[max];
        for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) { 
            temp[i] = s[i]; 
        }
        delete[] s;
        s = temp; 
    }
    s[elements++] = e; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the old array (`s`) instead of the new (`temp`):

```
delete[] s;
s = temp;
```

Also: make sure that your class has a proper destructor (deleting `s`).